# Integration on a subset

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

**Definition:** Let $(X, \mathcal{A}, μ)$ be a measure space.
Let $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function. Let $E\in \mathcal{A}$. Then
$$\int_E fdμ:=\int_X (f\chi_E)dμ.$$

Let $(X, \mathcal{A}, μ)$ be a measure space.
Let $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function. Let $E\in \mathcal{A}$. Assume that $\exists M>0$ s.t $$|f(x)|\le M,  \forall x\in E.$$ Then prove that $$|\int_E f dμ| \le Mμ(E).$$

Please help me in this proof. Definition is given above the proof of the statement.

My try:

$$|\int_E f dμ|=|\int_X (f \chi_E) dμ|$$
$$ \le \int_X |(f \chi_E)| dμ$$
$$= \int_X |f| |\chi_E| dμ$$
$$ \le  \int_X  M |\chi_E| dμ $$
$$= M \int_X |\chi_E| dμ$$
$$= M μ(E) $$

Comment: You need to make some vague effort. This is basic integration.

Comment: Ok. I put some efforts. Then pls tell me if I am going right.

Comment: Funny. I mean add your efforts to the question and indicate where you are having difficulty.

Comment: Your second last step is incorrect. You have $|f| \le M$ so first replace $|f|$ by $M$ inside the integral. Otherwise it looks good.

Comment: Is this okay now?

Comment: Looks good, you have a duplicate step, not that it matters.

Comment: Last question: $$\int_X |\chi_E| dμ=μ(E)$$???

Comment: How about now.   Is that true?

Comment: It is correct. $\int 1_E d \mu = \mu E$ follows from the definition since it is a simple funtion.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck.